# create_cloudsim.py issues

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

create_cloudsim.py has a couple issues.

1. It seems to depend on what directory it is launched in.
2. It is not clear what AWS credentials are needed.

create_cloudsim.py launched in cloudsim-1.0.1/bin: (the requests were made with a valid gmail account and "access keys" from AWS. Names and keys have been changed to protect the innocent)

```
./create_cloudsim.py xxx@gmail.com aslkfdjsklflsk askldfjlslksfjlksjl
inside/cgi-bin
cloudsimd/launchers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./create_cloudsim.py", line 40, in 
    import common
ImportError: No module named common
```

create_cloudsim.py launched in cloudsim-1.0.1

```
./bin/create_cloudsim.py xxx@gmail.com sklsklsdklskld slksdkldklssdkl
./inside/cgi-bin
./cloudsimd/launchers
./cloudsimd/launchers/cloudsim.py
Warning: redis not installed.
cloudsim log> cloudsim launch constellation 'b6c69e60-43bb-11e2-8dad-0014225a80ab'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/create_cloudsim.py", line 51, in 
    machine = cloudsim.cloudsim_bootstrap(username, tmp_fname.name)
  File "./cloudsimd/launchers/cloudsim.py", line 227, in cloudsim_bootstrap
  File "./cloudsimd/launchers/cloudsim.py", line 119, in launch
  File "./inside/cgi-bin/common/machine.py", line 729, in create_if_not_exists_web_app_security_group
  File "./inside/cgi-bin/common/machine.py", line 720, in get_security_groups
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 1861, in
get_all_security_groups
    [('item', SecurityGroup)], verb='POST')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 896,
 in get_list
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized

OptInRequiredYou are not subscribed to this
 service. Please go to http://aws.amazon.com to subscribe.
cb6d5e70-0c72-4eec-a3ab-e5e4f66aa490
```

Can you be more specific about AWS credentials one needs:

```
Access Keys?
Amazon CloudFront Key Pairs ?
Amazon EC2 Key Pairs ?
Your pointer to "AWS Key Pairs" on
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/cloudsim/setup  Introduction
actually points to #Access Keys, which are only one kind of key pairs.
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSecurityCredentials/1.0/AboutAWSCredentials.html#AccessKeys
```

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/485/create_cloudsim.py-issues/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Chris,

Sorry for the confusion. You need to use the "AWS access keys", AWS provides them on the Access Keys tab on the AWS Security Credentials page. I have updated my answer to your other question.

Using the AWS access keys should help you get your "Unauthorized" problem.

Hugo

---

Originally posted by [hugomatic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/59/hugomatic/) with karma: 116 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0